# PHP variables in HTML file with no PHP tags or echo

Tags: php, html, variables

I received some HTML files from a customer who says that some PHP values from one file are not passing through to another.

The first thing I thought was why are these files .html files and using PHP variables?

I also noticed that they dont use open and closing PHP tags or echo to display these variables.

Here is an example:

```
<p>Call us on our phone number<br /><span class="sbtelnum">$BrokerContactNumber</span>
</p>
                                <h1 class="sectionSubHeader">Opening hours:</h1>
                                <p>
                                    $BrokerOpeningHoursWeekdayLabel <span class="opentime">$BrokerOpeningHoursWeekdayHours</span><br />
                                    $BrokerOpeningHoursWeekendLabel <span class="opentime">$BrokerOpeningHoursWeekendHours</span><br />
                                    $BrokerOpeningHoursSundayLabel <span class="opentime">$BrokerOpeningHoursSundayHours</span>
                                </p>
```

These are being used in exactly the same way in File1 and in File2 but they do not display in File2 for some reason.

Yet these ones are displaying fine.

```
            <input type="hidden" name="Token" value="$Token"/> 
        $posted_fields
        $hiddenlist
```

So some variables do display correctly and some do not.

Can someone explain to me a reason why they would use .html files containing PHP variables and not enclose them within PHP tags or use echo? I have never seen it before.

Comment: They probably have another PHP file that's rendering those HTML files with the variables substituted in.

Comment: Sure, I thought about that but then i thought they would need to be echoing out all that HTML. There are no echo statements

Comment: Are they using a templating engine? This is not something php does natively so they are using a 3rd party or custom solution to do the rendering.

Comment: @Josh Trii Johnston I don't know whether they are or not but I can certainly ask. I was wondering if the reason they work in File1 is because they are being passed through via POST from a previous page which they havn't sent me and they dont work in File 2 because they are not being passed through. And putting them in hidden fields might work.

Answer (score -2):

Its impossible you cannot use php in a file with html extension plus to separate php variable you must enclose php code in  tags...

Comment: It's entirely possible to tell your webserver to send `.html` files through the PHP parser.

Comment: The second part of this answer is correct. You must enclose php code in `<?` in order for it to be processed by the engine. Everything else is implicitly `echo`d.